# WooCommerce: Hooking up product price in custom template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get some product prices to show up in one custom template. Is there, perhaps, an integrated woocommerce function that given ID will give me products price?

Something along the lines of: woocommerce_productprice(423)

Basically, I have a custom page template as a catalog and I want to hook product prices up to that template, so whenever something changes, it automatically changes the price without me having to change the custom template.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Updated for WooCommerce 2.3:

```
$product = we_get_product( $post_id );
echo $product->get_price();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$price = $product->get_price_html();`

woocommerce 3.x, it working!

Answer (score -1):

Here try this

```
$product = new WC_Product( $post_id );
$price = $product->price;
echo $price;
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually, there's a typo on the above code, see below:

```html
$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
echo $product->get_price();
```